# Параметры URL (net/http) GOLANG

Tags: golang

Как используя стандартную библиотеку net/http вытащить поле name:
localhost:8080/:name

у меня будет меняться название и нужно используя стандартную библиотеку получить из url name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен что у вас параметр задан правильно, исходя из [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) например. Чтобы извлечь параметр из адреса запроса достаточно использовать `url.Parse`:

```
urlStr := "https://example.com/?product=shirt&color=blue&newuser&size=m"
myUrl, _ := url.Parse(urlStr)
params, _ := url.ParseQuery(myUrl.RawQuery)
fmt.Println(params)
```

и так можно получить определенный параметр:

```
product := params.Get("product")

color := params.Get("color")
```

вот более полный пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {

    s := "postgres://user:pass@host.com:5432/path?k=v#f"

    u, err := url.Parse(s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(u.Scheme)

    fmt.Println(u.User)
    fmt.Println(u.User.Username())
    p, _ := u.User.Password()
    fmt.Println(p)

    fmt.Println(u.Host)
    host, port, _ := net.SplitHostPort(u.Host)
    fmt.Println(host)
    fmt.Println(port)

    fmt.Println(u.Path)
    fmt.Println(u.Fragment)

    fmt.Println(u.RawQuery)
    m, _ := url.ParseQuery(u.RawQuery)
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println(m["k"][0])
}
```

output:

```
$ go run url-parsing.go 
postgres
user:pass
user
pass
host.com:5432
host.com
5432
/path
f
k=v
map[k:[v]]
v
```

Comment: Вы все верно пишите относительно параметра. Он берется через метод get, но что если мне неизвестно что будет после localhost:8080/(какое-то имя)?product=shirt
Вот как product вытащить мне понятно. А как получить (какое то имя) ?
Типо gin там понятно, а используя стандартную библиотеку?

Comment: обновил ответ, надеюсь так получше будет :) то что вы хотите вытащить это не параметр, а path, вот более подробная информация - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)